# Xamarin Dependency Service Issue

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In Xamarin Forms i have a solution like this:

```
Solution
 |- Libraries
 |   |- IInterface.cs
 |   |- Etc.
 |
 |- Libraries.iOS
 |   |- Interface.cs
 |   |- Etc.
 |
 |- Forms.App
 |   |- App.cs
 |   |- Etc.
 |
 |- Forms.App.iOS
 |   |- Etc.
```

- Forms.App.iOS references Libraries.iOS
- Forms.App references Libraries
- Libraries.iOS references Libraries
- Forms.App.iOS references Forms.App

### IInterface.cs

```
namespace a
{
  public interface IInterface
  {
    void Function ();
  }
}
```

### Interface.cs

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(a.Interface))]
namespace a
{
  public class Interface : IInterface
  {
    public void Function ()
    {
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

### App.cs

```
namespace a
{
  public class App
  {
    public static Page GetMainPage ()
    {
      var inter = DependencyService.Get<IInterface> (); // This is always null.
      return new ContentPage { 
        Content = new Label {
        Text = "Hello, Forms!",
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
        },
      };
    }
  }
}
```

How can i make the dependency service locate my Interface implementation?
I need to have them in a separate project because i need the same implementations in different projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by creating a static class with an empty Init method. And calling the method at the beginning of AppDelegate.FinishedLaunching Method.

Comment: Hi, can you add a bit more detail for example:
In which library or app project did you create the static class? Which method did you call?

Comment: Can you please provide me the example of it. Where we need to create static class and how to use it.

Comment: It's an old thread. The problem was that the compiler was not compiling the classes. The static class was just calling a method from that project so that the compiler would be forced to compile the class.
This does not happen now.
I don't remember too many details because this was 2014.
Sorry if the thread didn't help.

Answer (score 6):

Adding a bit more information.
It seems to be a bug related to linking in the library that defines the dependency service as described [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/27436/dependencyservice-in-library-projects#latest).

I solved the issue by instantiating the iOS implementation of the dependency service manually.

In your iOS project in the AppDelegate.cs, FinishedLaunching method, create an object of the iOS dependency service implementation, e.g.

```
var obj = new Company.Project.iOS.NativeImplementation_iOS ();
```

That worked for me.

Comment: This is really great answer! Thank you!

Comment: regrettably [Preserve] didn't work for me but this did.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to work for me but if i have multiple interfaces then won't this have an important on memory consumption?

Answer (score 6):

I had

`[assembly: Dependency(typeof(TestService.IMyService))]`

, where I should have

`[assembly: Dependency(typeof(TestService.iOS.MyService))]`

So always take the implementation and not the interface in your platform specific code! Otherwise you get

> System.MissingMethodException: Default constructor not found for [Interface]

Answer (score 3):

It is because your Interface.cs implementation does not have an empty constructor.

For the DependencyService to work you MUST have an empty constructor as follows:

```
public Interface(){}
```

Yours Forms.App solution will have to reference the solution containing the Interface declarations.

Comment: I have did this thing but still giving error: "Default constructor not found for type 'myclass' xamarin ".

Comment: There's no need to create a constructor

Comment: @Dpedrinha you need a parameterless ctor to use dependency service in Xamarin (see https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction/)

Comment: Oh right! I missed the EMPTY in your statement. But if you don't have a constructor the compiler will add one. And according to his code there isn't one. So it should work.

Comment: Didn't work for me. Actually have to create the object in AppDelegate.cs as provided by @dutchman711 in answers.

Answer (score 3):

If you are getting null for your dependency, another reason can be that your type is similarly named as your service and the wrong type is declared in Dependency. At least that was the case for me.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe make sure you reference both the PCL library and the cross platform library

```
Forms.App.iOS
   references - Libraries
   references - Libraries.iOS
```

This worked for me